# What is soinside.com (StackOverflow Inside)?

Tags: discussion

While searching around for a fix for an issue, I noticed a very familiar post on a host that I didn't visit before. It turns out that it was the same post copied and then seemingly translated to Chinese (I think).

The page's structure appears to be rather similar and the tags look like they are basically copied over including CSS.

For reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794280/jest-fails-with-unexpected-token-on-import-statement) is the Stack Overflow post and [here](https://www.soinside.com/question/VNEKLKetfsegkTBjJADZh8) is what I am incredibly sure is the exact same post on soinside.com (formatting, single words that are formatted as code, etc. are matching).

What is soinside.com? What is the connection to Stack Overflow? Are they allowed to use the content from Stack Overflow? I couldn't see a link to the original post anywhere on that site.

Comment: My bad. I was looking for the hostname when searching. Will contact SO.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great signpost. I checked on MSE but there isn't a report there either. You can keep this one around.

Comment: Looks like there is no propper attribution. So definitely a case for the lawyers of the company to take on regarding licensing violations.